# yaml output with single escape?

Tags: yaml, escaping

I'm trying to get an output which is like `\#something`
but having a hard time. It seems to get converted to something double-escaped `\\#`

I've tried combinations using single and double quotes without luck

```yaml
        long:
          join \#team-01 to start
```

result

```
'join \\#team-01 to start'
```

this:

```yaml
long: "join \#team-01 to start"
```

gives a parser error unless I double escape it inside the double quotes `"\#team-01"

with a single quote I

```
        long: 'join \#team-01 to start'
```

I still get a double escaped output

```
'join \\#team-01 to start'
```

is there a way to get a parsed result with just a single backslash?

FWIW I'm using nodeJS and the `js-yaml` package
https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/583

Comment: Please create an [mcve]. You are not showing a single line of JS code. Also it's impolite to create an issue *and* a stackoverflow question without at least linking between them. You should have been asking first here and wait for answers.

Comment: js-yaml works correctly for me here. Using this code converting the YAML to JSON https://github.com/yaml/yaml-runtimes/blob/master/docker/node/testers/js-jsyaml-json I get this output: `{ "long": "join \\#team-01 to start" }`. Which is a single backslash, just escaped for JSON.

Comment: You are outputting `'` characters that don't exist in the input so it seems obvious that the output method you're using is not showing the string content, but a JS (or some other) string literal representing the value. And since you need to escape a backslash in a JS string, the value is correct.